# interactive Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, user-input, user-interaction

how do I create a simple Shell script that asks for a simple input from a user and then runs only the command associated with the predefined choice, for example

```
IF "ON"
Backup Server
ELSEIF "OFF"
Delete Backups
ELSEIF "GREY"
Send Backups
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take input from a user via `read` and you can use a `case ... esac` block to do different things.

Read takes as its argument, the name of the variable into which it will store it's value

```
read foo
```

Will take in a vaue from the user and store it in `$foo`.

To prompt the user for input you will need to use echo.

```
echo "What is your favourite color?"
read color
```

Finally, most shell scripts support the case operator. Which take the form

```
case "value" in
    "CHOICE)
        # Do stuff
        ;;
esac
```

Putting it all together:

```
echo "Which choice would you like? \c"
read choice

case "$choice" in

    ON)
        # Do Stuff
        ;;
    OFF)
        # Do different stuff
        ;;
    *)
        echo "$choice is not a valid choice"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: do I need to have that \c? And do I need to define the choices somewhere?

Comment: The `'\c'` is older syntax for suppressing the newline from echo, you can just use the `-n` flag if your system supports it. The choices for case can be literals, regexes or variables ( which will get interpolated ).

Comment: is there a way to show the choices that are there to the user?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

select choice in "ON" "OFF" "*"; do
case "$choice" in
    ON) echo "$choice"; # do something; 
    break;;
    OFF) echo "$choice"; # do something; 
    break;;
    *) echo "$choice other"; # do something; 
    break;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is simple example how to do it

```
while true; do
    read -p 'do you want to continue "y" or "n": ' yn

    case $yn in

        [Yy]* ) echo 'this program continue '; break;;

        [Nn]* ) exit;;

        * ) echo 'Please answer yes or no: ';;

    esac

done

while true; do
    read -p 'press "c" to quit this program: ' c

    case $c in

        [Cc]* ) exit;;

        * ) echo 'for quit this program press "c": ' ;;

    esac

done
```

for source click here [source](http://unixhacking.com/creating-interactive-yes-or-no-shell-script/)