# How do I make a cmd script that once it is run, remains open and accepts new commands?

Tags: cmd

I want to make a cmd script that performs an action but then remains open and I can type new commands.

I have failed to find the proper terms to google as my knowledge of shell is almost zero.

thank you!

Comment: On Unix, it seems simple ;):
ls;
bash

Comment: possible duplicate of [interactive Shell Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390593/interactive-shell-script)

Comment: not interested in linux or a switch, I want any command I want to be run.

Comment: which os are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a command shell to run a specific command during start-up using the `/k` switch.  E.g.

```
cmd /k C:\InitialScript.bat
```

The command shell would execute the `C:\InitialScript.bat` batch file and remain open for the user to type further commands.

If you want to create an icon for users to use then create a shortcut and use the following as the target:

```
%WINDIR%\System32\cmd.exe /K C:\InitialScript.bat
```

If you already have a command shell window open, then just use the following which will run the batch file in the context of the existing shell:

```
C:\InitialScript.bat
```

Comment: closer, but that would imply always having 2 cms, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would if you ran the first command in an existing shell.  Both the shortcut method and the existing command shell method (that I just added) use only one instance.